# Specify PHP code to select dates and records 3 days old

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to call data from SQL table that is only 3 days old

My table has a lbs-date column in it and is date format. I have tried the following but get no result from the query at all

```
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%y,%m,%d') FROM lbs_trace_etrack 
 WHERE lbs_date(datetime) = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
 ORDER BY lbs_date DESC")
```

Is there any other way I can call only the last 3 days of information from the SQL my date format is Y/M/D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(lbs_date, '%y,%m,%d') 
FROM lbs_trace_etrack 
WHERE lbs_date >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
ORDER BY lbs_date DESC
```

Comment: This works but is there away I can have it show the current date as well. it shows last 3 days excluding current date

Comment: Use `>=` to get dates 3 days ago and greater

Comment: Then use `date(lbs_datetime)`

Answer (score 0):

check [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format). Its syntax is  `DATE_FORMAT(<date>,format)` . Use like this :

```
SELECT *, DATE_FORMAT(lbs_date , '%y,%m,%d') FROM lbs_trace_etrack 
WHERE lbs_date = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY 
ORDER BY lbs_date DESC
```